# For a user that visits my site using referral link. Can I capture the source/medium of the visitor?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So, I created a referring element on my website. Suppose, user a refers it to user b. User b signs up using the same link. Traffic source is captured as direct/none instead of referrer/user_a but if user b refers it to user c the traffic source of referring event is captured as referrer/user_a but why it's breaking on sign up.
FYI - cross domain is also applied.
Can somebody help me to figure this out?

Comment: Please include the applicable JavaScript code related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have set in referral exclusions list the first domain o the domain is a third level of the second.